# Stop youtube video playback on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, youtube

Im trying to stop the youtube video when i click on another tab, but it only seems to work on the second time round.

```
<!-- click on these to switch the videos -->    
<div class="home-video-item" data-tab="tab-1">
    <img src="https://www.image.com"/>
</div>
<div class="home-video-item" data-tab="tab-2">
    <img src="https://www.image.com"/>
</div>

<!-- video boxes -->
 <div id="tab-1" class="home-video-content current">
    <iframe width="500" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qs74-Utqw?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

 </div><div id="tab-2" class="home-video-content current">
    <iframe width="500" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qs74-Utqw?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
 </div>



$('.home-video-item').on('click', function (e){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    var video = $("#"+tab_id).find("iframe").attr("src");

    $("#"+tab_id).find("iframe").attr("src",video);
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8oy0odas/

Comment: What form of tab are you talking about - is this an app tab or the browser tab? UPDATE: oh, i see. Well, i know how i'd do this in React... this doesnt help you though... hmmm.... lemme think

Comment: I've added a Jsfiddle

Comment: awesome... i was just re-creating your situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [IFrame player api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to pause the video with `player.pauseVideo()` :

```
<!-- click on these to switch the videos -->
<div class="home-video-item" data-tab="tab-1">
  video 1 play
</div>
<div class="home-video-item" data-tab="tab-2">
  video 2 play
</div>

<!-- video boxes -->
<div id="tab-1" class="home-video-content current">
  <iframe id="ytplayer0" width="500" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/x6kqVusK26c?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div id="tab-2" class="home-video-content current">
  <iframe id="ytplayer1" width="500" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/x6kqVusK26c?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Javascript in body :

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var players = new Array();
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  for (i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    players[i] = new YT.Player(iframes[i].id, {});
  }
}

$('.home-video-item').on('click', function(e) {
  for (i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    players[i].pauseVideo();
  }
})
```

Each time, a tab is clicked, all player are paused.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bmartel/8oy0odas/5/) is a working fiddle

Comment: Thanks for your help, just wondering.. is there a simpler method to pause all iframe videos when .home-vide-item is clicked? Rather than loading the players in the array.

Comment: If you mean without having the list of player id hard coded, see my updated post